# C# IMAP SMTP mail client for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, smtp, imap, email-client

I need a mail client library (IMAP and SMTP) for Windows Phone 8 or another alternative (like TcpClient, SslClient in Windows 8, but I don't get in Windows Phone 8). I google a lot. Please let me know any library or Article/Tutorial to implement IMAP and SMTP mail client on Windows Phone 8.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Doesn't [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) work on Windows Phone 8? As for IMAP there are a few libraries around... not sure how good they are.

Comment: No, `SmtpClient` is not available in Windows Phone 8. I already tried that. And for IMAP there is a [tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-IMAP-CLIENT-b249d2e6) to implement IMAP with `TcpClient` and `SslClient`, but These two TcpClient and SslClient also not available in Windows Phone. and not any additional library found.

Comment: WP8 doesn't even have TcpClient? Then I suppose you'll need to use sockets, assuming they are available. I'm very much interested in learning what WP8 supports since I'm writing my own IMAP library.

Comment: If you were targeting Windows Phone 8.1, you could use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit), but unfortunately, my MIME parser uses pointers which are not supported on Windows Phone 8

Comment: Yes @jstedfast , it is a great solution, but I want to target Wp8 and 8.1 both.

Comment: And @Gigi I also tried `Sockets` in Wp8. But they always return me an error message `NotConnected`. Actually I am trying to connect to gmail IMAP, then it returns me NotConnected , when used `Sockets`. Please let me know what is correct approach to use IMAP via Sockets. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: And Thanks @jstedfast for giving .Net community a great tool `MailKit`. Much appreciated your dedication and Thanks. But Please let me know any solution for WP8.

Comment: See my answer - sockets can be used in WP8, although they might possibly be a bit different from what we're used to. Read the official documentation to see how best to go about this.

Comment: No problem, I love the .NET community and wanted to give back the very best email library I could write :-)

Comment: @jstedfast - you are the man!!! Do post it as an answer for windows phone 8.1. True genius! Keep up the good work. Thank you again!!

Comment: Thanks all of you, I have found [this](http://www.limilabs.com/mail-for-windows-store) and it is working now for me, I can share code on github soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with [sockets in Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202874%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Apparently there is a new [Windows.Networking.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.sockets.aspx) API you can try using, but the classic one based on `System.Net.Sockets` should still work - [here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

You'd still have to implement IMAP and SMTP yourself though, unless some functionality already exists that we haven't spotted yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found [SMTP client for WinRT](https://www.nuget.org/packages/lightbuzz-smtp/)
which work for me

Answer (score 0):

I found this [link](http://www.limilabs.com/mail-for-windows-store) very useful for Windows phone 8.1

Make a class like MailManager in data model folder and add this line of code at the top of your class `using Limilabs.Mail;` also add this `Mail.dll` library to your project. [Read more](http://www.limilabs.com/blog/receive-unseen-emails-using-imap)

```
StorageFile imageFile = ...;
StorageFile attachmentFile = ...;

MailBuilder builder = new MailBuilder();
builder.Html = @"Html with an image: <img src="" cid:lena@@example.com""="">";
MimeData image = await builder.AddVisual(imageFile);
image.ContentId = "lena@example.com";
await builder.AddAttachment(attachmentFile);
builder.To.Add(new MailBox("to@example.com"));
builder.From.Add(new MailBox("from@example.com"));
builder.Subject = "Subject";

IMail email = builder.Create();

using(Smtp smtp = new Smtp())
{
    await smtp.Connect("smtp.server.com");  // or ConnectSSL for SSL
    await smtp.UseBestLoginAsync("user", "password");

    await smtp.SendMessageAsync(email);                     

    await smtp.CloseAsync();   
}
```